# Expired SSL certificate?

Tags: bug, ssl

I got an error when I visited [meta.politics.stackexchange.com](https://meta.politics.stackexchange.com):

```
meta.politics.stackexchange.com uses an invalid security certificate.
The certificate is only valid for the following names: *.askubuntu.com,
*.blogoverflow.com, *.mathoverflow.net, *.meta.stackexchange.com,
*.meta.stackoverflow.com, *.serverfault.com, *.sstatic.net,
*.stackexchange.com, *.stackoverflow.com, *.stackoverflow.email,
*.superuser.com, askubuntu.com, blogoverflow.com, mathoverflow.net,
openid.stackauth.com, serverfault.com, sstatic.net, stackapps.com,
stackauth.com, stackexchange.com, stackoverflow.blog, stackoverflow.com,
stackoverflow.email, stacksnippets.net, superuser.com The certificate
expired on 3 March 2021 at 7:30 PM. The current time is 13 January 2023
at 12:36 AM. (Error code: SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN)
```

Is it perhaps a wrong certificate that has been erroneously updated?

Comment: Where did you see that URL? Since a few years, the correct one is https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/ ...

Comment: @rene Thanks. That explains it. Should I delete this question?

Comment: @Glorfindel That makes sense. I didn't notice the mistake in the url as it resolved when I granted an exception.

Comment: No problem, just informing you that things are different now than they were four years ago :)